# Formatear fecha con hora a solo fecha PHP

Tags: php

llevo un buen rato tratando de convertir un formato de fecha y hora a solo fecha para poderlas restar.

Lo estoy haciendo así:

Primero que todo traigo los datos de fecha desde la bd y los declaro en una variable asi:

Código PHP:

```
 $f1 = $row['f_cre']; 
$f2 = $row['f_sub_arc'];
```

Aclaro que el formato que llama de la base de datos me viene así: 12-09-2020
(15:21:52:PM), porque al guardarlo lo declaro así:

```
date( 'd-m-Y (H:i:s:A)' ).
```

Ahora, quiero convertir esos formatos a solo d-m-Y, lo cual lo estoy haciendo asi:

Código PHP:

```
$ff1 = date_format($f1, 'd-m-Y'); 
$ff2 = date_format($f1, 'd-m-Y');
```

De esta forma al imprimirlo no me muestra nada.

Probé también convirtiendo el formato así:

Código PHP:

```
$ff1= strtotime($f1, 'd-m-Y'); 
$ff2= strtotime($f2, 'd-m-Y');
```

Cuando lo imprimo así, me muestra como fecha 1-12-1979 y no las fechas reales de la bd.

Quiero formatear las fechas al formato indicado porque quiero establecer la deferencia entre las dos fechas, lo cual lo estoy tratando de hacer así:

Código PHP:

```
$fecha2 = new DateTime($ff1); 
$fecha1 = new DateTime($ff2); 
$fecha = $fecha1->diff($fecha2); 
printf('%d años, %d meses y %d días.', $fecha->y, $fecha->m, $fecha->d);
```

Pero que creen? no funciona porque no logro formatear las fechas quitando la hora con la que se llama por defecto de la BD.

Por favor si me pueden dar una luz, les estaré agradecido.

Comment: Y ya que te viene bien formateadita de la base de datos, por qué no simplemente cortas el trozo que necesitas?? `$ff1 = substr($f1, 0, 10);` Si te fijas, tus fechas siempre van a tener 10 caracteres porque están en formato dd-mm-aaaa, con lo cual cogiendo las 10 primeras posiciones del string de la fecha tendrás exactamente lo que buscas.

Comment: Y por qué tanto trabajo? Si usas mysql por qué en tu Select no solo haces `DATE(columnaFecha)` eso quitará el tiempo y solo dejara la fecha

Comment: Gracias por las respuesta voy a probar sus ideas y les cuento como me fue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigos para cerrar la pregunta, quiero comentarles que con el método sugerido por  ***Benito-B***, me dio el resultado que estaba esperando.

Gracias a ***Benito-B***

> $ff1 = substr($f1, 0, 10);

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que indicas estas guardando la fecha en formato `'d-m-Y (H:i:s:A)'`, por lo que supongo que el campo es VARCHAR y no DATETIME. Para efecto de calculos, orden y cualquier cosa relacionada, es mejor usar DATETIME y el formato por defecto `'Y-m-d H:i:s'`.  Si luego deseas entregar una fecha formateada (ej:`d-m-Y`) puedes hacerlo con la funcion MySQL `DATE_FORMAT()` o desde PHP con `date('d-m-Y',strtotime($fecha))`.

Ahora si la informacion ya esta formateada asi, para poder convertirla a un formato trabajable en PHP, se debe usar la funcion `DateTime::createFromFormat ($formatString,$dateString)`. Se obtiene un objeto `DateTime` :

```
$fecha1="12-09-2020 (15:21:52:PM)";
$datetime1=DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y (H:i:s:A)',$fecha1);
```

Para hacer la operacion completa, se convierten ambas fechas y se ejecuta el resto del codigo:

```
$fecha2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y (H:i:s:A)',$f1); 
$fecha1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y (H:i:s:A)',$f2); 
$fecha = $fecha1->diff($fecha2); 
printf('%d años, %d meses y %d días.', $fecha->y, $fecha->m, $fecha->d);
```

Por otro lado, `date_format( DateTime, string)` espera como primer parámetro un objeto DateTime, una cadena con la fecha no funcionará, por ello retorna una fecha invalida.

Ademas, usar el formato `H:i:s:A` para la hora es redundante en cuanto a la hora (`H` es hora en 00-23 y `A` es AM/PM), por lo que el generalmente se usa `h` en combinacion con `A` (ej: `h:i:s A`).

https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.createfromformat.php